# Freeing a linked list that points to an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct

I have a linked list

```
typedef struct LinkedList {
    Element* arrayOfStruct;
    struct LinkedList* next;
    } LinkedList;
```

that points to an array of structures, called arrayOfElements,  that contains the structures called Element.

```
typedef struct {
    char colName[30];
    data_type type;
    void* data;
    } Element;
```

First the head of the Linked List was initialized

```
struct LinkedList *head =NULL;
```

then arrayOfElements was malloc'd

```
Element* arrayOfElements;
arrayOfElements= malloc(columns * sizeof(Element));
```

each element of arrayOfElements was malloc'd

```
arrayOfElements[ii].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
```

and finally each new node of the Linked List was malloc'd

```
LinkedList* insertNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
```

How would I go about creating a function where I just import the head and all allocated memory is freed?

I imagine it would be something like this

```
First LL node ---->
Free all the elements of arrayOfElements ---->
Free arrayofElements itself ------->
traverse to 2nd Node ----->
Free First Node
CYCLE UNTIL NO MORE LINKED LIST NODES
```

My code:

```
void FreeList(LinkedList* head, int columns)
    {
        Element* arrayPtr;
        void* elementPtr;
        for (ii=0 ; ii<columns; ii++)
        {
           //arrayptr points to the ii instance of arrayOfStruct
           arrayPtr = &head->arrayOfStruct[ii];
           //elementPtr points to the data member of the struct Element
           elementPtr = arrayPtr ->data;
           free(elementPtr);
           free(arrayPtr);
        }
        //frees linked list
        free(head);
    }
```

I doubt that is the correct way to do it and I'm not to sure when you add the line to go to the next node.

Comment: Your suggested approach seems like a good one. Why don't you give it a try and update your question if it isn't working.

Comment: AFAICS, you have to be able to identify `arrayOfElements` accurately so you can free that. It isn't clear to me that you can do that with just the `head` — you have to know coincidentally which pointer corresponds to `arrayOfElements`. Basically, for each `malloc()`, you must identify where the corresponding `free()` will take place. Freeing something not returned by `malloc()` leads to chaos (usually); not freeing something returned by `malloc()` leads to memory leaks. (`malloc()` includes `calloc()` and `realloc()` — there are extra twists with `realloc()`, but the basic idea is the same.)

Comment: Or is what you call `arrayOfElements` actually the structure member `arrayOfStruct`?  If so, then you managed to confuse me — and the compiler would likely object — and your outline code would be more or less OK.  The 'one `malloc()`, one `free()`' advice remains valid.  You don't need the `arrayOfElements` separately because it is `arrayOfStruct` (or `arrayOfStruct` is `arrayOfElements`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah its a bit odd arrayOfStruct is the Element* that the Linked List uses to point to an instance of arrayOfElements

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you have any suggestions as my current code is giving me errors about double free

Comment: It would be easier if the code that allocates the stuff were more visible.  I don't know how `arrayOfStruct` (a structure member) and `arrayOfElements` (not visibly a structure member) are used and interrelated. I can't immediately see how your collection of data structures are woven together, and can't see how to pick them apart. Can you create an MCVE ([MCVE]) that does a good enough job allocating? Do you have code to print your structures? You end up with one printing function per structure. They're useful tools; you can use them in many places. They often show how the freeing should work.